# Separate exit for stop loss and target

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am coding a strategy in pine script where i have set the exit at a certain stoploss and target price.It looks like this:

```
if useStopLoss
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Long","Long", stop=stop_level, limit=take_level,comment="exit_buy")
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Short","Short", stop=stop_level_short, limit=take_level_short,comment="exit_sell")
```

The issue here is I am using {{strategy.order.comment}}  in my alerts but i am not able to differentiate if the stoploss is triggered or It has reached the target.
I tried doing the following:

```
if useStopLoss
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Long","Long", stop=stop_level,comment="stop_buy")
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Short","Short", stop=stop_level_short,comment="stop_sell")
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Long","Long", limit=take_level,comment="target_buy")
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Profit Short","Short",limit=take_level_short,comment="target_sell")
```

here i made separate exits for stop loss and target. But for some reason it doesn't work as intended.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: For get `action` of filled order you can use `{{strategy.order.action}}` placeholder. Here https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000481368 is more info

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `strategy.order` to exit your positions. Also, in the meantime you can use alert_message instead of comment and in the alert use `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}`.

Something like this should work; the direction based on IS_LONG variable is the reverse direction versus initial orders that opened position:

```
strategy.order(id="take_profit", limit=take_profit_price, long=(IS_LONG?false:true), qty=strategy.position_size, when=(strategy.position_size != 0), alert_message="write here")
```